# Rotate UIImage by CGAffineTransform

Tags: objective-c, swift, uiimage, orientation, cgaffinetransform

I have a video(taken from the device album), which i'm applying `CGAffineTransform` in order to "fix" his rotation.

When i'm trying to fetch out a frame, the rotation of the image is wrong(Even if i'm enabling generator preferred transform).

```
 let assetImgGenerate : AVAssetImageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset.asset)
 assetImgGenerate.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
```

I thought about fetching the "unfixed" image from the generator, and than apply my Video `CGAffineTransform`.But it didn't worked so far.

**Any suggestions on how to generate/manipulate the UIImage, to achieve the same orientations as the video?**